# React Redux - Manage dependencies between reducers

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I want to know how to manage dependencies between reducers.

Let's say you fire some action, and there are two reducers "listening" to this action, but you want one of them to run before the other one does.

Example:
You have reducer of ingredients and reducer of meals (meals consist of ingredients).
Every reducer takes the fetched data from the server, makes cast objects out of it and save them i the store (for instance - the ingredients reducer makes an aray of Ingredient objects and return it as the new state).
Every ingredient has a unique id.
A Meal  of gets a listingredients ids (the ingredients it contains) in the constructor, then fetch the relevant ingredients objects from the store and add them as an attribute of Meal.
For reasons of efficiency you fetch all the data (the ingredients and the meals) together from the server (one GET request).
When you fire FETCH_ALL_DATA_FROM_SERVER (with the fetched data as payload) - you want both the ingredients and the meals reducers to "listen" to this action:

1. The ingredients reducer should parse the ingredients raw info that
   was fetched from the server into cast Ingredient objects, and store
   them in the Store.
2. The meals reducer should parse the meals raw info that was fetched
   from the server into cast Mael objects, and store them in the
   Store.

But here is where it gets tricky - what if the meals reducer tries to create a Meal object that contains ingredients that are not in the store yet (the ingredients reducer hasn't load them to the store yet)?

How can I solve this problem?
Thanks in advance :)

---

UPDATED

---

Code example:
The fetching action looks something like that:

```
export function fetchAllDataFromDB() {
    return dispatch => {
        axios.get('http://rest.api.url.com')
            .then(response => {
                dispatch({
                    type: FETCH_ALL_DATA_FROM_DB,
                    payload: response.data
                })
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log(error)
            })
    }
}
```

The ingredients reducer looks something like that:

```
export default function reducer(state={}, action) {

    switch (action.type) {
        case FETCH_ALL_DATA_FROM_DB: {
            // Create the Ingredient objects from the payload
            // They look like Ingredient(id, name, amount)

        }
    }

    return state
}
```

The meals reducer looks something like that:

```
export default function reducer(state={}, action) {

    switch (action.type) {
        case FETCH_ALL_DATA_FROM_DB: {
            // Create the Meal objects from the payload
            // They look like Meal(id, name, price, ingredients_ids)
            // It will try to fetch the ingredients (of ingredients_ids) from the store - and fail, because hey are not there yet.
        }
    }

    return state
}
```

The problem is - you can't create the Meal objects before the ingredints reducer is done loading the relevant ingredients to the store.

---

UPDATED

---

I haven't really solved the problem, but wat I did is:
I changed the Meal constructor so it won't fetch the Ingredient objects from the store, but will stick with the ingredients_ids list.
I also added a getter that fetches the Meal objects from store.
It might be better this way, because now I can change the ingredients a meal is consist of dynamically (not that I want to...).
It's less efficient though...
If you find a better solution I'd really like to know.

Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you could search more on topic about asynchronous in javascript.

in general if you wish to wait for 2 or more action to complete before running another method. You could use [Promise.all()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all), or nest the callback into callback hell or use [async.series()](http://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#.series) library. Back to redux, you could make sure that all your queue has finished running before rendering( dispatch() )

Also my recommendation is to learn Promise instead of async library.

example case:

```
fetch().then( res => dispatch({type: "I_GET_THE_DATA", payload: res.data}))
```

you could even chain fetch if you want.

```
fetch(mealURL).then( res1 =>{
   fetch(ingredientsURL).then(res2 => {
       var meal_and_ingredients = {
          meal: res1,
          ingredients: res2
       }


       dispatch({type: "GET_TWO_DATA", payload: meal_and_ingredients})
   })
})
```

Comment: I do use Promise, and I do dispatch FETCH_ALL_DATA_FROM_SERVER in the callback. But this doesn't solve the problem, because once I dispatch FETCH_ALL_DATA_FROM_SERVER - both the reducers (ingredients and meals) start working asynchronously. What I would like to do is somehow make the ingredients reducer dispatch LOAD_MEALS action once it's done.

Comment: I am not sure about why do you dispatch a fetch to database? because in react-redux, dispatch is to tell react to rerender.. usually fetch is by click or after DidMount, then whatever the value returned, will be processed, finally to be dispatched

Comment: I don't see how this changes anything... what if I had a "Load Data From Server" button - would that make any difference?

Comment: you should provide a sample code, but I will try to assume a case and update the answer

Comment: I saw the code you added to your answer. Now let's think what is going to happen when you dispath I_GET_THE_DATA/GET_TWO_DATA - both the ingredients and the meals reducers will start working immediately. And what will happen if the meals reducer finishes before the ingredients reducer - well, then I'll get errors when I'll try to render the meals, because they'll try to render their ingredients by their ids - but they won't find ingredients with those ids in the store! because they are not there yet!

Comment: you should provide a code, i can only assume.. a big question is why the state/reducer have to be dependent on each other? I mean does it necesarry to structure  the code that way... if so,  you might consider dispatching two action.. so the meal will render from meal_id, then the ingredients will render from it's id,  whichever render first.. I  can't imagine structure like that on top of my head